# Find a Basis, eigenvectors of M.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions

Given matrix $M$

$$ M= \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\2&0&-1&0\\0&7&0&6\\0&0&3&0 \\  \end{bmatrix} $$

1. Find a Basis for the Null-Space of $ M$.
2. Does $(2, 2, 3, 3)$ belong to the Null space of$ M $? (Explain).
3. Find the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues of $M$.
4. Show that M is similar to a diagonal matrix and give all the needed matrices ($P$ and $D$).

---

for part 1) I got no basis so it is a trivial..

for part 2) I tried to think of making span but the problem is there is no basis 
for nullspace so can anyone give me a hint or solution for it?

for part 3) I found the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues of M, $x_1 = -2 , x_2 = 2 , x_3 = -3 , x_4 = 3 $ 
the problem is in part 4 is that i need to show that by this equation $M=P^(-1) D P$ .. can anyone help me to find $P$ and $D$ so that i can proceed..
Please help me as much as you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the basis of a null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/finding-the-basis-of-a-null-space)

Comment: This Question seems to present difficulties with parts 2 and 4 (similarity), and you've proposed a duplicate about finding a null space with a matrix of less than full rank (where here the OP apparently found the matrix has full rank).  I don't the proposed duplicate is closely related.

Answer (score 3):

Given 
$$ \mathbf{M} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 0 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
the determinant is nonzero:

$$
 \det \mathbf{M} = 36
$$

No eigenvalues are $0$. This matrix has full rank. Both null spaces are trivial:
$$
 \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{M} \right)} = \mathbf{0}, \qquad
 \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{M}^{*} \right)} = \mathbf{0}
$$

---

**Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra**

Given a matrix
$$
\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$$
the four induced subspaces can be expressed as
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbb{R}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{M}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{M} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbb{R}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{M} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{M}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

In this problem $m=n=\rho=4$, and there are no nullspaces. The two range spaces are 
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \text{Row }\mathbf{M} &= 
\text{span} \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, 
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]},
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]},
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\} = \mathbb{R}^{4}\\[5pt]
%
  \text{Col }\mathbf{M} &= 
\text{span} \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, 
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]},
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]},
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\}
%
 = \mathbb{R}^{4}
%
\end{align}
$$

---

**(a) Null space basis**

Both null spaces are trivial and are empty bases, as noted by @Omnomnomnom.

**(b) Is $x$ in the null space?**

Immediate answer: since the null space is trivial there are no null vectors such that $\color{red}{x}\in\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{M} \right)}$ such that 
$$
\mathbf{M} \, \color{red}{x} =  \mathbf{0}
$$
In fact, 
$$
\mathbf{M} x =
\mathbf{M}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 1 \\ 32 \\ 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**(c) Eigenvalues**

The characteristic polynomial is defined as
$$
 p(\lambda) = \det \left( \mathbf{M} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{4} \right)
= \det 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & -\lambda & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & -\lambda & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -\lambda \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The *roots* of the *characteristic polynomial* are the *eigenvalues*.

Attack using [minors and cofactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)). Level I:
$$
\det \left( \mathbf{M} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{4} \right) =
- \lambda \det 
\underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -\lambda  & -1 & 0 \\
 7 & -\lambda  & 6 \\
 0 & 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)}_{\mathbf{S}}
-
\det
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{array}{crc}
 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -\lambda  & 6 \\
 0 & 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
}_{\mathbf{T}}
\tag{1}
$$
Level II:
$$
%
\begin{align}
%%
  \det \mathbf{S} &= 
\det 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -\lambda  & -1 & 0 \\
 7 & -\lambda  & 6 \\
 0 & 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
= -\lambda
\det 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -\lambda  & 6 \\
 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
+
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 7 & 6 \\
 0 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
-\lambda^{3}+11\lambda \\[4pt]
%%
  \det \mathbf{T} &= 
\det 
\left(
\begin{array}{crc}
 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -\lambda  & 6 \\
 0 & 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)%
= 2
\det 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -\lambda  & 6 \\
 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
2\lambda^{2} - 36 \lambda
%
\end{align}
%
$$
Use these results in (1)
$$
\det \left( \mathbf{M} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{4} \right) =
- \lambda \left( \lambda^{3} - 11\lambda \right)
- \left( 2\lambda^{2} - 36 \lambda \right) 
$$

Characteristic polynomial:
$$
\boxed{
p(\lambda) =  \lambda^4 - 13 \lambda^2 + 36
= \left( \lambda^{2} - 9 \right) \left( \lambda^{2} - 4 \right) =
\left( \lambda - 3 \right)
\left( \lambda + 3 \right)
\left( \lambda - 2 \right)
\left( \lambda + 2 \right)}
$$
Spectrum:
$$
\boxed{
\lambda\left( \mathbf{M} \right) =  \left\{ \pm 3, \pm 2 \right\}
}
$$

**(d) Eigenvectors**

Given the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and the eigenvalues $\lambda_{k}$ find the eigenvectors $v_{k}$ which solve the eigenvalue equation
$$ 
\mathbf{M} v_{k} = \lambda_{k} v_{k}, 
\qquad \left( \mathbf{M} - \lambda_{k} \mathbf{I}_{4} \right)  v_{k} = \mathbf{0}
\quad k = 1,2,3,4
$$
The four eigenvectors follow. 
$$
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{M} - (-3) \mathbf{I}_{4} \right) v_{1} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 3 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array} 
\right)
v_{1} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right) 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
v_{1} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ -3 \\ -7 \\ 7
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{M} - (3) \mathbf{I}_{4} \right) v_{2} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 3 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array} 
\right)
v_{2} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right) 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
v_{2} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ -3 \\ -7 \\ 7
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{M} - (-2) \mathbf{I}_{4} \right) v_{3} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 2 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
v_{3} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right) 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
v_{3} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ -2 \\ -2 \\ 3
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{M} - (2) \mathbf{I}_{4} \right) v_{4} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & -2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & -2 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_{4} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right) 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
v_{4} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ -2 \\ 2 \\ 3
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{align}
$$

Examples of reductions for finding null spaces are [Finding the basis of a null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/finding-the-basis-of-a-null-space?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Deriving left nullspace of matrix from $EA=R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263139/deriving-left-nullspace-of-matrix-from-ea-r/2263153#2263153), [Give bases for col(A) and null(A)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522796/give-bases-for-cola-and-nulla/2266062#2266062), [Given a matrix and its reduced row echelon form, resolve the image and the kernel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857727/given-a-matrix-and-its-reduced-row-echelon-form-resolve-the-image-and-the-kerne/2261304#2261304), [Find base and dimension of given subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932435/find-base-and-dimension-of-given-subspace/2261396#2261396)

The matrix of eigenvectors is
$$
  \mathbf{P} = 
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 v_{1} &
 v_{2} &
 v_{3} &
 v_{4}
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -3 & -3 & -2 & -2 \\
 -7 & 7 & -2 & 2 \\
 7 & 7 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

To invert the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ use reduction and elementary row operations on the augmented matrix.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{P} & \mathbf{I}_{4}
\end{array}
\right)
\quad \rightarrow \quad
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{E_{P}} & \mathbf{P}^{-1}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The first operation which clears column 1 is 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -7 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr|cccc}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -3 & -3 & -2 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -7 & 7 & -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 7 & 7 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%%
=
%%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr|rccc}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -6 & 1 & -5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 5 & -5 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 14 & -4 & 10 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The complete sequence of elementary matrices is clear columns 4, 3, 2, 1:
$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cccr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{3}{10} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{10} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrc}
 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{30} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{crcc}
 1 & -\frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{14}{6} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -7 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The above product is the inverse matrix:
$$
\mathbf{P}^{-1} = 
\frac{1}{10}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -2 & 3 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 7 & -7 & 1 & -3 \\
 -7 & -7 & -1 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
%
\boxed{
\begin{align}
%
% 
 \mathbf{P}^{-1} \, \mathbf{M} \, \mathbf{P} &= \mathbf{D} \\
%
\frac{1}{10}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -2 & 3 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 7 & -7 & 1 & -3 \\
 -7 & -7 & -1 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 0 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -3 & -3 & -2 & -2 \\
 -7 & 7 & -2 & 2 \\
 7 & 7 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
 &=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -3 & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 3 & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & -2 & \color{gray}{0}\\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
}
%
$$

Comment: @Amsar: Trivial nullspace implies no basis. The column space and row space are dimension $4$. Use the canonical basis for these spaces: the $4$ basis vectors are columns in $\mathbf{I}_{2}.$

Comment: @Amsar: Your statement on resolving the range spaces is correct. However, note the spans for both row and column space are $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Yet another reason to eschew square matrices. It's confusing to sort the bases.

Comment: A trivial space has an "empty basis", but it technically has a basis.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That was a hair I was reluctant to split. Glad you brought it up.

Comment: Guys, what about part 4.. how to show that M is similar to diagonal matrix?